# Vanishing integral for spacelike separated points

Tags: definite-integrals, quantum-field-theory

The integral I have is this:
$$
K(x,y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \sin(p(\theta) \cdot (x-y)) \ d\theta\ 
$$

where 
$$
p(\theta) = m\begin{pmatrix} \cosh(\theta) \\ \sinh(\theta) \end{pmatrix} \quad (m>0),
$$
and $x$ and $y$ are points in Minkowski space.

For simplicity here, I am considering $\mathbb{R^{1+1}}$ so $1$ time dimension and $1$ space. Also the $\cdot$ is the Minkowski inner product: $x\cdot y = x_0y_0 - x_1y_1$ in this case.

This integral should vanish for spacelike separated points $x$ and $y$, but I don't know how to show this.

Comment: Don't you mean that $x$ and $y$ are spacelike seperated?

Comment: I'm sorry, yes. That is exactly what I should mean - I will make a quick edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $x$ and $y$ are spacelike seperated, the vector $v = x-y$ will be such that
$$
v \cdot v = v_0 v_0 - v_1 v_1 < 0.
$$
Now you can find a Lorentz transformation $\Lambda$ such that
$$
v' = \Lambda v = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 \\ r \end{matrix} \right)
$$
where $r = \sqrt{-v \cdot v}$. To be more explicit there's a $\alpha$ such that
$$
\Lambda = \left( \begin{matrix} \cosh(\alpha) & \sinh(\alpha) \\ \sinh(\alpha) & \cosh(\alpha)  \end{matrix} \right).
$$

Now note that we have $p(\theta) \cdot v = \left( \Lambda p(\theta) \right) \cdot \left( \Lambda v \right) = p(\theta+\alpha) \cdot v'$. So we find
$$
K(x,y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \sin(p(\theta) \cdot v ) d\theta = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \sin(p(\theta+\alpha) \cdot v') d\theta = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \sin(p(\theta) \cdot v') d\theta 
$$
where the last equality is acquired by using substitution. So really the only integral you have to calculate is
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} \sin(-mr \sinh(\theta)) d\theta =\lim_{m \to \infty} \int_{-m}^m \sin(-mr \sinh(\theta)) d\theta,
$$
and because $\theta \mapsto \sin(-mr \sinh(\theta))$ is an odd function, $\int_{-m}^m \sin(-mr \sinh(\theta)) d\theta$ is zero for every $m>0$.

Comment: This is all very informative and will help a great deal when it comes to what I have to do next so thank you! However, the question I really have was why this final integral is 0. I can see it should be (graphically speaking), but mathematically proving it is the struggle I have.

Comment: @CharleyScotford So you know $\sin(-mr\sinh(\theta))$ is an odd function?

Comment: Indeed, and generally the integral over a symmetric interval of an odd function is 0, but I wasn't sure if we could use this rule for the whole real line. Is this what we can use?

Comment: @CharleyScotford I edited my answer a bit to justify this. Note that the integral probably doesn't converge in the usual sense (meaning as an improper integral), but the Cauchy principle value (which is often used in Quantum field theory) obviously will as I demonstrated.